# Facebook 2.1 API get home feed and sort by type

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I've tried searching and can't find an answer..
I've tried to get my own feed with just one or several type like "link" or "video".

I played with the facebook explorer tool, i've got my own feed with the endpoint me/home but i don't known how we can sort by type (link, status, video or photo)

Someone has an idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is available in the docs, but explained a little complicated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/home/

The parameter `filter` can be used to

> Retrieve only posts that match a particular stream filter. Valid filters to be used here can be retrieved using the FQL `stream_filter` table.

The docs for `stream filter` are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/
 You can query your own stream filters by issueing the following FQL query:

```
select name, filter_key from stream_filter where uid=me()
```

Test it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20name%2C%20filter_key%20from%20stream_filter%20where%20uid%3Dme()&version=v2.0

This yields in the following filters (at least for me):

- Photos: `/me/home?filter=app_2305272732`
- Videos: `/me/home?filter=app_2392950137`
- Links: `/me/home?filter=app_2309869772`
- Statuses: `/me/home?filter=app_2915120374`